# Улетает объект когда навожу на него мышкой

Tags: unity3d, объекты

Нашел урок где делается плавное передвижение физических объектов по карте с помощью кнопок. Я решил сделать чтобы перемещения было только с помощью мыши (т.е куда смотрит курсор, там и находится объект). Но когда я навожу на объект он улетает в сторону курсора. На самом объекте стоит Rigidbody и BoxCollider. Cave это земля на котором двигается объект

```
    using UnityEngine;

//эта строчка гарантирует что наш скрипт не завалится ести на плеере будет отсутствовать компонент Rigidbody
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    // т.к. логика движения изменилась мы выставили меньшее и более стандартное значение
    public float Speed = 1f;

    //что бы эта переменная работала добавьте тэг "Ground" на вашу поверхность земли
    float raycastLeight = 100;
    private Rigidbody _rb;
    RaycastHit _hit;
    private Vector3 movement;

    void Start()
    {
        _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }


    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (GlobalVar.activeCreateUnit == true)
        {
            GameObject _target = GameObject.FindWithTag("CreateUnit");
            Ray _ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            if (Physics.Raycast(_ray, out _hit, raycastLeight))
            {
                if ((_hit.collider.name == "Cave") && (_target != null))
                {
                    // в даном случае допустимо использовать это здесь, но можно и в Update.
                    // но раз уж вызываем здесь, то 
                    // двигать будем используя множитель fixedDeltaTimе 
                    MovementLogic();
                } 
            if ((GlobalVar.onTriggerUnit == false)&&(Input.GetMouseButton(0)))
            {
                GlobalVar.activeCreateUnit = false;
            }
            if(Input.GetMouseButton(1))
            {
                Destroy(_target);
            }
        }
    }
}

    private void MovementLogic()
    {
        Vector3 mousePosition = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, 0, Input.mousePosition.y);
        movement = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);
        movement = new Vector3(movement.x, 0, movement.z);

        // что бы скорость была стабильной в любом случае
        // и учитывая что мы вызываем из FixedUpdate мы умножаем на fixedDeltaTimе
        transform.Translate(movement * Speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: непонятно что ты хочешь получить в итоге. Перемещение обьекта за движением мышкой? Телепортация обьекта в место клика? Плавное перемещение в место клика? Хорошо опиши что ты хочешь на практике получить.

Comment: Да и статья та, из которой ты код брал не для того что бы копировать код одтуда, а просто что бы показать основные ляпы или что можно вообще сделать. Например, в следующем скрипте была лучше реализация `IsGrounded` на которую стоило бы обратить внимание.

Comment: Реализовать я хочу чтобы объект двигался за курсором мышки и не отставал от нее.

Comment: Мне прыжок там не нужен я его убрал, мне надо чтобы просто ездил плавно по земле с помощью курсора